# Wicket: How to post a Feedback Message from within the FeedbackPanel

Tags: wicket

I have a form with ComponentFeedbackPanels. I have implemented a Filter, that removes the FeedbackMessage shown in the ComponentFeedbackPanels (I have adapted [this solution](http://www.jeremythomerson.com/blog/2011/01/catching-all-feedback-messages-that-arent-rendered-by-other-feedback-panels/)) from the top-of-the-page FeedbackPanel. 
Now I would like to add a Feedback Message to the top level to remind the users to read CompnoentFeedback Messages that are displayed next to the form fields. 
I don't know how to add such a message. Calling error() from within that filter or FeedbackPanel or the parent page when already filtering does not add anything to the current FeedbackPanel...

Comment: Just an idea: how about adding it every time then make the filter remove it if not needed?

Answer (score 1):

To add a top-level message, use `Session.get().error(message)`.